# issues with .sortable function in J query

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, containment

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nemi9/76JPk/2/) I'm working with.

I'm trying to create two lists from which I can move each item in and out between them and changes will update below inside the update function / sort status div area.

My first alert on line 3 works but when I call the click function on line 5 line 6 alert doesn't work. Overall I think my code may be missing something or a semi colon etc. is out of place. Please help and leave feedback, thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert(0);
 $(".shopping_list").onclick(function() {
    alert(1);
    $("#names #places").sortable({
         containment: 'parent', 
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        cursor: 'pointer', 
        revert: true, 
        opacity: 0.60,
        connectWith:"#names #places",
        update: function(event, ui) {
             content = $(this).text();
              $('#sort_status').text(content);
        }
    })

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [grissom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3173775/grissom) pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24438458/2333214) and comments,

- Firstly you need to add `jQuery-UI`.
- `$("#names #places")` searches for an element`#places` inside an element `#names`. To select both the elements, you need to comma separate them like `$("#names , #places")`.
- You should move the sortable initialization out of the click event.

Other than that:

- You need to remove [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-containment): `'parent'` otherwise you can't drag the item out of the current list *(hence you can't move items between the lists, obviously)*

  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/76JPk/14/)
- Unless you want the `<h3>` headers to be sortable *(this is also invalid `HTML`)* - you need to move them out of the `<ul>`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/76JPk/13/)

Comment: Thanks Grissom you've help me tremendously this is my new fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Nemi9/76JPk/15/ with both of your suggested changes.  I think I fixed the issue. Tilwin Joy you are also correct I need to move the H3 out and I change parent to document. Now for some reason this works in fiddle but not in my browser?

Comment: are you sure you've correctly linked to jquery, jquery ui and the code in wrapped in `$(document).ready()` function..? also check for error in console...

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
`$("#names #places")` this means that you have element which id is "names" and that element has child with id "places".

You have to setup sortable each list.
Also:
`$(".shopping_list").onclick` should be:

```
$(".shopping_list").click
```

Comment: I have updated and I have setup each list as .sortable but both list does not respond. I got all three of my alerts to work but that just on when I click on the list. my updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/Nemi9/76JPk/4

Comment: Doesn't work because you didn't include jqueryui.js library. try now: http://jsfiddle.net/76JPk/6/

Comment: Also you can remove on click for list, because on load you can initialize sortable http://jsfiddle.net/76JPk/7/